# Android animation andEngine

Tags: android, ios, animation, andengine, sprite

I was working over iOS Application that i wrote animation for it using coreGraphics. The animation was basically a circle that has items over it. when you press over an item, all other items collapse under it and makes a shadow. Now, i want to port that animation over Android. I have a good understanding with AndEngine, How can i do that ??

thanks[image]

[image]

Comment: You want it that when you click on item it will change its color?(have shadow) ?

Comment: No, it will collapse them under the one that i clicked over

Answer (score 0):

I think he means this scenario : 
1) click on any item. for example, item " Card 1 " 
2) All other cards ( items ) should be rotated and moved under Card 1
3) He needs to rotate and move all cards to be under card 1. but in circular path not in linear path.

Answer (score 0):

according to @user2511303 explanation and my knowledge of AndEngine:

You need to give every card a rotation value.
Whenever you click on the number `X card`, iterate through all your cards and rotate them to the same rotation the `X card` has.

You need to use `EntityModifier`

You can rotate the cards using `RotationModifier` class

To move them under card number X, for linear path you can use the `MoveModifier` class.

If you want to make an circular path, you will need to implement your own `Modifier`. (for example `CircularModifier` ) .

In order to execute the modifiers simultaneously, you should use the `ParallelModifier` class.

Hope it helps.

[Circular Path AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles1/moving-sprite-around-a-fixed-point-t4063.html#p49789)

[Entity Modifiers](http://www.matim-dev.com/entity-modifiers.html)